# Safari Crashing on Clearing Download List

Tags: macos, safari

Safari crashes when I click the clear button on the Safari download list. I am using an M1 Macbook Air with macOS Monterey (12.0.1) and have encountered this issue multiple times in the past month. I want to know if it is a common issue that has been addressed by Apple or if there is something wrong with my system in particular. A snippet of the console log is as follows.

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Can you share your crash report?

Comment: Please share your **full** report, not a snippet.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. Most of the times when clearing the downloads list in Safari it crashes. [Full crash report](https://pastebin.com/QJBDctWs)

Comment: Please update Safari to the latest version (15.2) and check if this issue is still happening. You may have to install Monterey 12.1.

Comment: @Ezekiel Yes, I think the latest update has fixed it. I was just surprised that many people did not have this problem.

Comment: @Ezekiel No, Unfortunately I am still facing that issue, are you too?

Comment: I never experienced this issue, so unfortunately I can't help :(

Comment: I am also still experience this issue on Version 15.2 (17612.3.6.1.6).